# Create property dynamically in viewmodel MVVM light and UWP

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, binding, dynamicobject

I would like to create viewmodel properties in runtime.

I'm not so familiar with MVVM in UWP. Rather windows forms. In the past I created custom class object with reflection and I had possibility to add properties in runtime. 
In current project I prepared solution with mvvm ligt and UWP app. Works fine with data exchange on viewmodel level. Now I try to find how to create properties of viewmodel in runtime ie. from descriptions in xml file.

```
namespace hmi_panel.ViewModels
{
    public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Fields
        readonly IPlcService _plcService;
        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public HomeViewModel(IPlcService dummyPlcService)
        {
            _plcService = dummyPlcService;
            _plcService.Connect("127.0.0.1", 0, 1);

            //zdarzenie cyklicznego odswiezania zeminnych
            OnPlcServiceValuesRefreshed(null, null);
            _plcService.ValuesRefreshed += OnPlcServiceValuesRefreshed;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public string AppVersion
        {
            get { return $"{Package.Current.Id.Version.Major}. 
{Package.Current.Id.Version.Minor}.{Package.Current.Id.Version.Build}. 
{Package.Current.Id.Version.Revision}"; }
        }

        public string AppCopyright
        {
            get { return "plc service: " + _plcService.ConnectionState.ToString(); }
        }

        private bool _pumpState;
        public bool pumpState
        {
            get { return _pumpState; }
            set {

                 _pumpState=value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => pumpState);

            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods
        private RelayCommand _ConnectCommand;
        public RelayCommand ConnectCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _ConnectCommand ?? (_ConnectCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    pumpState = true;

                }, () => true));
            }
        }

        private void OnPlcServiceValuesRefreshed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            pumpState = _plcService.PumpState;

        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Property pumpState value is readed and writed with _plService. I can change value and I can read after external change. 
I would like to start only with bidirectional binding in xaml and create needed property ie. pumpState when viewmodel instance is created ie. in construtor.

Comment: I've helped you format your code. Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your post next time.

Comment: I actually did not quite understand what you want to do. Did you want to use **TwoWay** bindings to change your property's value on XAML?

Comment: Yes I did. Property value in viewmodel is changed in proper way. I just want to create properties in viewmodel not in code but in runtime ie. from some description list.

Comment: You could bind it on XAML and set `Mode=TwoWay`. For example, you could bind the `CheckBox`'s IsChecked to `pumpState` property. `<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding pumpState,Mode=TwoWay}" Content="descript"></CheckBox>` Then, when the CheckBox checked or unchecked, the `pumpState` property's value will be changed.

Comment: That's done. It works. My goal is to do not define property pumpState in static code but build viewmodel object properties in runtime.

Comment: It's impossible.